# Facebook class not found in PHP request?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm a first time user of Facebook API: I'm trying to fetch events from a specific Facebook page like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/src/Facebook/autoload.php';  
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/src/Facebook/Facebook.php';
$fb = new Facebook(array(
   'appid'=>'myID',
   'secret'=>'mySecret'
  ) );
$page_events = $fb->api('/ikeausa/events', 'GET');
printf ('<pre>%s</pre>', $page_events);
?>
```

Both paths exist in these exact locations (I've double checked). However I still get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in /mypath.php on line 10
```

line 10 is this one where I create the Facebook object. 
Can anyone help what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The classes are namespaced, so you need to include the namespace as well. Have a look at the examples under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/5.0.0#examples, that should make things clear.

Comment: @CBroe what namespace should I use in your opinion? I looked at the examples you linked but they don't include a namespace declaration...

Comment: Of course they do – right in the first one, you can see how it uses `$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(…)`

Comment: @CBroe well. I obviously don't understand what you mean by "define a namespace" since I looked at this link from php reference http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php
and namespace delcaration looks like this: "namespace myNamespace" this is not included in the examples anywhere. Can you tell me how my example should look like? I'm really not understanding. That's why I asked here in the first place...

Comment: I did not say _define_ a namespace, but include the namespace when you initialize the class. Again: You need to use `$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(…)` in your code, instead of just `$fb = new Facebook(…)`

Comment: that then just throws another error: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Required "app_id" key not supplied in config and could not find fallback environment variable "FACEBOOK_APP_ID"' in myUrl/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/src/Facebook/Facebook.php:133 Stack trace: #0 mypath.php(14): Facebook\Facebook->__construct(Array) #1 {main} "

Comment: `'appid'` != `'app_id'`